# Word for someone who is very well-spoken and eloquent, but shallow?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word sophist/sophistry came to mind but after googling to make sure I’m not fully certain it matches up 100%, given that it’s more about fallacious arguments than the “weaponized eloquence” by someone who is wrong or lacks the depth his words suggest. Just wanted to confirm that there’s no better word for this!

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319790/word-for-superficial-but-unmerited-appearance-of-substance-character https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314025/name-for-having-no-concern-about-the-truthfulness-of-one-s-own-remarks/

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: How about [glib](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glib)?

Answer (score 0):

**Pretentious** can fit as in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious) it defined as **making usually unjustified or excessive claims (as of value or standing)**.

> Dressed in a ball gown, she made an overly pretentious appearance at the simple high school dance [[YourDectionary]](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/pretentious).

َAnother suggestion is [**glib-tongued**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/glib-tongued) as someone who intended or having the power to induce action or belief (but I could not find any example that glib-tonguedness roots in being superficial but I found in real life that such persons are more prone to be shallow!).

Also, however not a single word, [empty as a drum](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/empty-barrels-make-the-most-noise), can work to refer to the situation introduced in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bombastic),

> If you describe someone as **bombastic**, you are criticizing him for
> trying to impress other people by saying things that sound impressive
> but have little meaning.

It often relates to a pompous or grandiloquent manner of speaking, sometimes used by *smooth talkers*.

Answer (score 0):

An adjective used to describe eloquent, fluent but facile, insincere, shallow, or hollow speech is **glib**. That's the first word that came to mind, and I see Kate Bunting thinks the same.